# Crystal report export to multiple tabs of excel

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Hi I have a report with in section as group. each group is having 1000 records and each group information should come in different tab of excel. As i know there is no direct method to export to excel in different tabs with sap crystal as it is a limitation of crystal. Is there any workaround to add each group into different tab of same excel output. I am using vs2010 to create reports with oracle package.procedure as backend. taking ref cursor output to report.

Answer (score 0):

You can burst the report creating a separate excel file for each group and then join all the files in one excel file. You can implement this in your application or to use one of the tools available on the market. There 2 report schedulers able to do this: R-Tag and Visual Cut. R-Tag has also a report viewer, which can export to multiple worksheets and will be a cheaper solution compared to the scheduler. You might check also if this feature is available in their free license.